# Mongo - transitively finding all group ids for a user

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Given the following documents:

```
{ _id : "1", groups : [ "2", "3" ] }
{ _id : "2", groups : [  ] }
{ _id : "3", groups : [ "4" ], users : [ "a" ] }
{ _id : "4", groups : [ ] }
```

I want to find all the groups that user "a" belongs to transitively, so the query result should be `1` and `3`, as group `1` contains group `3` (which contains the user), and group `3` directly contains the user.

I thought about using `graphLookup` but that won't work because I can't know which groups might contain the user. In theory, I thought about something like:

- For each group, transitively find the user "a".
- If there's a match, return all the group IDs in the process.
- Distinct at the end.

I'm not sure how to achieve such thing in Mongo, or if my theory is correct. This is what I have so far, but it's only returning the groups that directly contain the user:

```
db.getCollection('groupstest').aggregate([
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "groupstest",
      startWith: "$allGroups._id",
      connectFromField: "groups",
      connectToField: "_id",
      as: "allGroups",
      maxDepth: 100,
    },
  },
  { $unwind: "$allGroups" },
  { $match: { "allGroups.users": "a" } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      allGroupsIds: { $addToSet: "$allGroups._id" },
    },
  },
  { $project: { _id: 0, allGroupsIds: 1 } },
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe we can think "backward". We can start from the groups that contain user a. Then, we can `$graphLookup` back the parent groups that contain those groups. Use `$reduce` to iterate the lookup result and put the path into an array using `$setUnion`.

```js
db.groupstest.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      users: "a"
    }
  },
  {
    "$graphLookup": {
      "from": "groupstest",
      "startWith": "$_id",
      "connectFromField": "_id",
      "connectToField": "groups",
      "as": "allGroups",
      "maxDepth": 100
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id :0,
      allGroups: {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$allGroups",
          "initialValue": [
            "$_id"
          ],
          "in": {
            $setUnion: [
              "$$value",
              [
                "$$this._id"
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5YTIlLAl28U)